# Encoding type in Android-manifest causes problems with: finding default activity and compilation process

Tags: android, android-manifest

I am new in android development and currently, I am working on a small application as a part of university classes. I came across a strange problem for me. In AndroidManifest.xml I have field "encoding" set to some encoding-type. Depending on how it is set causes various problems:

**1. Set to 'utf-8'**
    During compilation "Content is not allowed in prolog" error occurs

**2. Set to 'utf-16'**
    Sometimes I am not able to compile my project because IDE can't find default activity.

Could someone explain what the problem might be and why project behaves in this way?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?><manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.bayex.bayex">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:configChanges="orientation"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".BaseSelectedActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".ShowBaseActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".HipothesisDisplay" />
    <activity android:name=".SymptomsDisplay" />
    <activity android:name=".Expertise_display" />
    <activity android:name=".MetawaysDisplay" />
    <activity android:name="com.bayex.bayex.Expertise_display$ShowAnswers"/>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to remove this line and check again

```
<activity android:name="com.bayex.bayex.Expertise_display$ShowAnswers"/>
```

**EDIT**

delete `AndroidManifest.xml` and create again

make sure it have UTF-8 encoding format in first line

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Comment: I did remove this line and I'm not sure if it helps with 'utf-16' setup because it was working before but with 'utf-8' it is still the same problem, some logs: ```Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/C:/dev/projects/bayex/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml;```

Comment: Creating a new AndroidManifest.xml worked for this problem. I restored this line ```<activity android:name="com.bayex.bayex.Expertise_display$ShowAnswers"/>``` because without it, one of the functionalities didn't work. Thank you very much for  help :)